# Use a website template in my web application project in VS12

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web

I am creating a web site and I was given a website template that has various html pages and javascript that my website will reference. I wanted to  know if this is possible to add those files and reference them in my project or if I am going about this the wrong way.

First time building a website but I have experience building applications, just confused on the right way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Add a master page to your website and replace it's html by the html of your template. add a content place holder in it so that controls can be placed in content pages. copy image, css , and jquery(if any) folders in website. if your css and images are not shown in design of master page then replace Image to ../Image in its html and source of css ../(your file name)